# The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion

Tags: vb.net, recursion

I am currently trying to create a simple client (Initiator) using QuickFix with a graphical user interface. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and programming in VB.Net.

Here is my problem :
When I launch my app, I have this error : "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe

Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion.  Within the Form's constructor refer to the form using 'Me.'"

I have two files in my project which are Client GUI.vb (http://pastebin.com/virgVNyS) and MyQuickFixApp.vb (http://pastebin.com/tQ1GXNSx). The second one contains the class that integrates the IApplication, with all the subs.

The error happens when it executes this line : "Dim initiator As New SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)" from Client GUI.vb
but the software highlights a line from the file Application.Designer.vb which is :

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
    Me.MainForm = Global.WindowsApplication1.ClientGUI
End Sub
```

Can you help me and tell me what is wrong ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with WinForms, the best proceeding to avoid problems is initialise everything (except simple variable assignation, for example: `Dim filename As String = "initiator.cfg"` is fine) after the GUI has been constructed/loaded (on the `_Load` method). The reason why you are getting this error is because of referring to the main Form (`Me.MainForm =`) before it has been actually created.

Move `Dim initiator As New SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)` to `ClientGUI_Load` (the `Load Event` method of your main form) and the error will disappear.

NOTE: if you want to access `initiator` from "anywhere", you should keep the global declaration but move the assignation to the Load event, that is:

```
Dim initiator As SocketInitiator 'at the Class level, outside any sub/function (as previously)
```

And

```
initiator = New SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory) 'Inside the ClientGUI_Load method.
```

Comment: Thank you, this problem is solved :) but it created another one : now it's telling me that initiator is not declared, on lines "initiator.Start()" and "initiator.Stop()". I tried different things but I didn't succeed to correct the error.

Comment: @WilliamGéraldBlondel Let the global declaration as it was originally (Dim initiator As SocketInitiator) and just move the assignation (initiator = New SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)) to the Load event. Will update my answer right now.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem; I'm hoping my description of it and the solution I found may provide clarity to others in the future.

I declared two constants for a grid background color. Selected rows should be yellow. I also said that nonselected rows should be the default background color of one of the grids on the form:

```
Private MatchColor As Color = Color.Yellow
Private NormalColor As Color = MyFormsDataGridView.BackgroundColor ' <<< this line is bad.
```

This was in the form's declarations section, before any code could run! I got the error and was flummoxed for hours. I even read this post but it didn't sink in.

The problem of course is that I was referring to a property of a grid on a form that had not yet been instantiated!

The solution was:

```
Private MatchColor As Color = Color.Yellow
Private NormalColor As Color = Color.White ' <<< this is the fix.
```

Then it loaded just fine!

I hope that helps.