# An error occurred creating the form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I just don't understand where I went wrong in my code. I have identified the line where error is but I don't know how to correct it or else what causes it. please help, any suggestions would be most welcome. Here is where the problem lies: Just along line 2 of code

```
Public Class Form2
Dim ThirdForm As New Form3
Dim Randomize()

Dim check As Integer = 0
```

Comment: You don't `Dim` methods, you call them - like this: `Randomize()`.

Comment: The exception detail and the code of form would help. As a side note, I don't think "Dim Randomize()" is correct.

Comment: when I remove "Dim" the Randomize methods shows an error - declaration expected.

Comment: Here is the exception detail: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion.  Within the Form's constructor refer to the form using 'Me.'

Comment: The code you posted cannot generate this exception message.  Post better code.

Answer (score 2):

Dim is the keyword to use when you want to declare a variable, not when you want to call a function 
Randomize() is a function that initializes the random-number generator and **you cannot call it outside any method of your class**

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim ThirdForm As New Form3 ' Declare and initialize the variable ThirdForm
    Dim check As Integer = 0   ' Declare and initialize the variable check

    ' Inside a form constructor....
    Public Sub New()
        Randomize() ' Call the function that initializes the random-number generator
    End Sub

    Public Sub Form_Load(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' In alternative you call it inside the Form_Load event.
        ' Randomize() ' Call the function that initializes the random-number generator

    End Sub
```

Comment: Still not working after implementing your suggestions.

Comment: Please, explain what is not working. Do you have any error messages?

Comment: Problem solved, got help from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437664/the-form-referred-to-itself-during-construction-from-a-default-instance-which-l